# Can I connect to new table log serilog?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, logging, serilog

I am already connected with a table(logs1) in my .net core application which use serilog. But I am not able to create new table by changing the name in appsettings.

When I drop the table manually, run the application with new name(logs2) in the appsettings, logs are recorded in logs1 only

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "***********;Initial Catalog=ewaybill_auth;User ID=sa;Password=nic@1234; MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
          "tableName": "Logs2",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "customColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "ErrorCode",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "AllowNull": true,
                "DataLength": 50
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "ReqId",
                "DataType": "bigint",
                "AllowNull": true
              }
            ],
            "disableTriggers": true,
            "clusteredColumnstoreIndex": false,
            "primaryKeyColumnName": "Id",
            "id": { "nonClusteredIndex": true }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Are these appsettings actually those that get used when you run the application? Or are they still the old ones? We once had an issue, where someone added to and changed some appsettings but they weren't actually deployed.